# SNMPv3 on AIX from Linux shows authentication failure

Tags: linux, aix, snmp

I want to use snmpv3 on AIX, the client is Linux which use snmpwalk command

On AIX side I first create the hash of the password

```
pwtokey -p HMAC-SHA -u auth mypass 192.178.0.37
```

the command return this line

```
Display of 20 byte HMAC-SHA localized authKey:
  18de41acdd2c8f0a1cb24f875g611198ea23e990
```

Then I edit /etc/snmpdv3.conf

```
cp /etc/snmpdv3.conf /etc/snmpdv3.conf.orig
vim /etc/snmpdv3.conf
```

and I add those lines

```
USM_USER u1 - HMAC-SHA 18de41acdd2c8f0a1cb24f875g611198ea23e990 - - L -
VACM_GROUP group1 USM u1 -
VACM_VIEW group1View            interfaces         - included -
VACM_VIEW group1View            tcp                   - included -
VACM_VIEW group1View            icmp                  - included -
VACM_VIEW group1View            system             - included -
VACM_VIEW group1View            sysObjectID        - excluded -
VACM_ACCESS  group1 - - AuthNoPriv USM group1View - group1View -
NOTIFY notify1 traptag trap -
TARGET_ADDRESS Target1 UDP 192.178.0.37    traptag trapparms1 - - -
TARGET_PARAMETERS trapparms1 SNMPv3  USM     u1        AuthNoPriv -
```

I restart all daemons

```
stopsrc -s aixmibd
stopsrc -s hostmibd
stopsrc -s snmpmibd
stopsrc -s snmpd
startsrc -s aixmibd
startsrc -s hostmibd
startsrc -s snmpmibd
startsrc -s snmpd
```

Now I run smpwalk from Linux client..

```
snmpwalk -v3 -u u1 -a SHA -A "mypass" 192.178.0.37
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2 = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)
```

I have tried also

```
snmpwalk -v3 -l authNoPriv -u u1 -a SHA -A "mypass" -x DES -X "mypass" 192.178.0.37
snmpwalk -v3 -l authNoPriv -u u1 -a SHA -A "mypass" -x AES -X "mypass" 192.178.0.37
```

but fail with

```
"snmpwalk: Authentication failure (incorrect password, community or key)"
```

Of course the pass is correct

What I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found.
SNMPv3 on AIX require snmp.crypto and is not installed on my system

```
lslpp -cl snmp.crypto
lslpp: Fileset snmp.crypto not installed.
```